Search for text while typing in field and return closest match
I wonder if an Excel wizard could help me with this.
I have a list of addresses, I'm trying to work out a formula or array that will enable the user to search for an address in a field on one sheet that finds the closest match from the address list on another sheet while the user is tying in the address, similar to when you start typing your address on shipping websites and it find the best address match as you type in the postcode or part of the address...hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance for your help :)

I've tried the SEARCH function but I think what I need will require a combination of formulas and possibly an array.
